# Rollbacking XML feature

Tags: c++, xml, libxml2

I've seen that [C# has a rollbacking feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927457/rollbacking-changes-in-xml-document) for Xml documents, and [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720573/how-implement-rollback-feature) suggest to copy the previous structure: I would like to avoid this last implementation, since that will require a huge waste of memory for heavy XML documents.

In particular, I want to trace

- The initial state of the document
- Each element that has been removed or added
- Have the possibility to rollback and eventually restore the undoned operations.

Is there a library that provides this features on XML documents using libxml or libxml++? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

the only sane way i can think of is to take a diff of the the various documents in a directory, having a history of diff you can regenerate the old ones with ease.

rdiff-backup do something like this for doing general filecopy, it mantain the last copy of a dir/file and a directory with all the information that are needed to regenerate the old ones.
https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/non-gnu/rdiff-backup/